# Count attributes, then use every specific occurrence

Tags: xml, xslt, count

So I want to count the number of nodes with "wd = 1" as an attribute, and I want to do something with, say, the 4th 9th and 15th occurrence of "wd = 1". How can I do this?

I know how to count the total occurrences for a certain thing, and I know that I could use 'for each' if I wanted to do something with every occurrence, but I don't have a clue how to do this.

This is a snippet of the original XML I'm working with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="XSLT Stylesheet.XSL" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--XML document generated using OCR technology from Nuance Communications, Inc.-->
<document xmlns="http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<page ocr-vers="OmniPageCSDK18" app-vers="OmniPage 19">
<description>
<source file="C:\Users\danielsteele\Pictures\7740411202.jpg" dpix="300" dpiy="300" sizex="3375" sizey="2330"/>
<theoreticalPage size="Custom" marginLeft="134" marginTop="40" marginRight="45" marginBottom="1184" offsetY="-84" width="16200" height="11184"/>
<language>en</language>
</description>
<body>
<section l="14275" t="40" r="15715" b="228">
<column l="14275" t="40" r="15715" b="228">
<para l="14308" t="84" r="15697" b="197" alignment="left" spaceBefore="2" lsp="exactly" lspExact="174" language="en">
<tabs position="14308"/>
<ln l="14669" t="84" r="15631" b="197" baseLine="182">
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0">Page</wd>
<tab position="14669"/>
</run>
<run underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c"><wd l="15185" t="89" r="15218" b="194">1</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="15326" t="84" r="15470" b="197">of</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="15595" t="89" r="15631" b="194">1</wd>
</run>
</ln>
</para>
</column>
</section>
<dd l="139" t="266" r="8777" b="3762">
<dd l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1807" backColor="d3d3d2" bottomDistance="375">
<bottomBorder type="single" width="2" color="d7d7d7"/>
<dd l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1807">
<table l="4297" t="266" r="8777" b="1803" alignment="left">
<gridTable>
<gridCol>3899</gridCol>
<gridCol>581</gridCol>
<gridRow>1537</gridRow>
</gridTable>
<cell gridColFrom="0" gridColTill="0" gridRowFrom="0" gridRowTill="0" alignment="left" verticalAlignment="top">
<para l="4373" t="367" r="6322" b="679" alignment="left" li="72" spaceBefore="53" lsp="exactly" lspExact="197" language="en">
<ln l="4373" t="367" r="6322" b="482" baseLine="480" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c" forcedEOF="true">
<wd l="4373" t="367" r="4572" b="480">HP</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4618" t="367" r="4944" b="480">VAT</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="4985" t="370" r="5213" b="482">No:</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5388" t="367" r="6322" b="480">GB314149679
</wd>
</ln>
<ln l="4373" t="562" r="5738" b="679" baseLine="677" underlined="none" subsuperscript="none" fontSize="800" fontFace="Times New Roman" fontFamily="roman" fontPitch="variable" spacing="0" foreColor="0c0c0c" forcedEOF="true">
<wd l="4373" t="562" r="5446" b="679">Hewlett-Packard</wd>
<space/>
<wd l="5491" t="562" r="5738" b="677">Ltd.</wd>
</ln>
</para>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using 1, but can use 2 if that's easier. I'm still new to this whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "4th 9th and 15th occurrence" is NOT "every nth one". To do "something" with every n-th occurrence, you can test for `position() mod n`. For example:

```
<xsl:if test="not (position() mod 3)">"
    <xsl:attribute name="something">
        <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

will add an attribute to every third element of the elements being processed.

To pick specific occurrences that do not follow a definable pattern, you'll need to construct a list and check if the current position appears in it or not.

**ADDED**

> how would I construct said list and check against it?

To construct the list, you could define a variable, say:

```
<xsl:variable name="positions" select="'-4-9-15-'" />
```

Then check against the list by:

```
<xsl:if test="contains($positions, concat('-', position(), '-'))">
    <xsl:attribute name="something">
        <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Note that this is a rather primitive example. A more flexible method would keep the selected positions in an external XML document (or even within the stylesheet itself) *as a set of nodes* - then have the stylesheet consult that set with a simple `position() = set` comparison.

---

**ADDED #2**

Here are two examples you can try out using the w3schools Tryit Editor. The first one *marks* the records in the selected positions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="positions" select="'-4-9-15-'" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Mark</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="contains($positions, concat('-', position(), '-'))" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This one, OTOH, *selects* only the records in the indicated positions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="positions" select="'-4-9-15-'" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[contains($positions, concat('-', position(), '-'))]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I couldn't think of a way to describe what I wanted in the title in few words. But what you mention at the end is what I want - how would I construct said list and check against it? Thanks for your time

Comment: @user2606105 Please add an example XML input to your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I'm still trying to get it to work though!
I'm using [W3School's tryit editor](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3) to test it.
I put in 
`<xsl:variable name="positions" select="'-4-9-15-'" />


<xsl:if test="contains($positions, concat('-', position(), '-'))">

    <xsl:attribute name="catalog/cd">

        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>

    </xsl:attribute>

</xsl:if>` but it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2606105 Comments are not a good place to debug code. I have added two example stylesheets to my answer for you to try out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2 and you have an arbitrary set of numbered occurrences of an element you can  easily match them using a sequence. For the sake of this example, I've made this more verbose than really required. I'm assuming an element `foo` with an attribute `bar`:

```
<xsl:variable name="all-foos-with-bar" select="//foo[@bar]"/>
<xsl:variable name="interesting-indices" select="(4, 9, 15)"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$all-foos-with-bar[position() = $interesting-indices]"/>
```

The `xsl:apply-templates` statement is using XPath 2.0's general comparison operators which allows you to compare sequences (remember, that a value is considered to be the same as a sequence containing one item). When comparing sequences for equality with the general operators then the comparison that occurs is "does any value in the LH sequence equal any value in the RH sequence".